How to test the Vhidmini2 windows driver?
I am new to windows driver development.
I am trying to create virtual HID user mode driver in windows. While browsing I came across below link:
https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/main/hid/vhidmini2
Followed below link to build and deploy the vhidmini2 driver:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/gettingstarted/writing-a-umdf-driver-based-on-a-template
I am not able to deploy the build umdf2 vhidmini2 to the test system.
Windows mainly emphasizes on setting up test computer to testing.
Approach1: using vm to test.
Always fails with error:
Driver Testing
A driver test group has not been selected. Please select a test group in the test group combo box on the driver tool bar.

Could not figure how to get rid off this error
Approach2:I trying to use the other machine for testing purpose only. Made sure both the host and test are ping-able. while provision the test system, stuck here forever.(target machines sign out and and logged in to "WDKRemoteUser" account and test system is ping-able from host)
Below is the log info;
Installing necessary components...
Removing TAEF test service
    Task "Removing TAEF test service" completed successfully
Copying required files
    Task "Copying required files" completed successfully
Configuring WDK Remote User Account
    Task "Configuring WDK Remote User Account" completed successfully
Installing .NET Framework (possible reboot)

Any help is really appreciated, thanks in advance.
